# arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type datetime

Tags: overflow

I've this simple update statement

```
    UPDATE EmpSchedual2
    SET AttH = 0, AttM = 0, AttC = 'AM', DisH = 0, DisM = 0, DisC = 'PM', changeDate = 0
    WHERE  (EmpID = 4) AND (WeekDay = 2)
```

I get this error when run:

- arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type datetime

and this is the table definition:

```
    Column Name DataType
    Serial      int 
    EmpID       int 
    WeekDay     int 
    AttH        int 
    AttM        int 
    AttC        char    
    DisH        int 
    DisM        int 
    DisC        char    
    changeDate  int 
    WorkM       int
```

Can someone figure why i receive this error?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you

I'm sorry for posting such question.

I  found the error in a trigger attached to that table